# Show that the powerset partial order is a cartesian closed category.

Tags: category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

I'm trying to get started learning category theory.  A problem I'm working on is to show that for a set $S$, the partial order $(\mathcal{P}(S),\subseteq)$ viewed as a category is cartesian closed.

So far, I was thinking that $S$ is the terminal object, and that the product of any two subsets $A \times B$ always exists (the greatest lower bound or intersection of $A$ and $B$), but am having trouble completing the proof by showing that the category has exponentiation.

If I understand right, the goal is to show that for any $A$ and $B$, there is a $C$ such that $C \times A \to B$ (i.e., $(C \cap A) \subseteq B$) if and only if there is a $B^A$ such that $C \subseteq B^A$ and $(B^A \cap A) \subseteq B$. But then this doesn't seem quite right.

I'm sorry for such a beginner question. I'd really appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction or maybe clarifying what/how one would go about showing that this category has exponentiation - or what does "$B^A$" mean in terms of these subsets? Does some sequence of operations construct it?

Comment: Think in terms of logic. This is the poset of all logical statements you can make about members of the set $S$, where there is a unique morphism $a \to b$ if $a$ entails $b$. The categorical product behaves like logical and. So what logical operation should correspond to exponentiation?

Comment: **Heuristically**: Exponentiation $B^A$ is "morally" the function space $A\to B$, and trough the Curry-Howard isomorphism, this corresponds to the _implication_ $A\Rightarrow B$, which is the same as $\neg A \lor B$, and since $\mathcal P(S)$ is a Boolean algebra, this **suggests** that it might work to take $B^A$ to be $(S\setminus A)\cup B$. (Or might not).

Comment: Thanks, your comments definitely help. I'll see if I can finish it from there.

Comment: Henning: I think that you are cheating :-) You had known the conclusion in advance, wrote a *wrong* justification, and then called it a "heuristic". You cannot use the Curry-Howard isomorphism when $A \Rightarrow B$ is logically equvalent to $\neg A \vee B$. Simply because the corresponding types are not equivalent. (cont)

Comment: For example there is a generic function (the identity) belonging to $A \Rightarrow A$ and one may prove that there is no such a generic function belonging to $\neg A \vee A$. You may say: ha, there is also a variant of Curry-Howard isomorphism for classical logic --- but you know, this isomorphism does not deal with cartesian closed categories.

Comment: J.B.: You made a mistake in stating the universal property for the exponent: we have to show that for any $A$, $B$ and *every* $C$ your equivalence holds.

Comment: @Mockup: I don't think Henning's comment is cheating. The power set is a Heyting algebra, so one could get to $A\implies B$ by Curry-Howard, and *then* use that classical logic is available to get from there to $(\neg A)\lor B$. On the other hand, I'd disagree with Henning's decision to use Curry-Howard in a comment for someone who says (s)he is "trying to get started learning category theory."

Comment: @J.B.: Amplifying Mockup's last comment: You have to show that, for every $A$ and $B$, there exists some $B^A$, such that for every $C$, $C\cap A\subseteq B$ if and only if $C\subseteq B^A$.

Comment: @Mockup: No, actually I _don't_ know the conclusion. My heuristic argument explains how I'd choose the first thing to try if I had the inclination to attempt to verify a solution.

Comment: @Andreas: put it another way --- a simply typed lambda calculus with a naive law of excluded middle is necessary degenerated. Therefore, it *is* a classical propositional logic. I do understand that a degenerted cartesian closed category is the same thing as a Heyting algebra, and I do understand that the internal language of any cartesian closed category is a simply typed lambda calculus (this is a part of the Lambek correspondence). What I do not understand is how one could apply the Curry-Howard isomorphism to get the above.

Comment: BTW: it is well-known that a cartesian closed category having *isomorphisms* $\neg \neg A \rightarrow A$ for every object $A$ is necessary degenerated. It is not so well-known that it suffices that there exists a *natural* morphism $\neg \neg A \rightarrow A$ to make a cartesian closed category degenerated.

Comment: That is indeed not-so-well-known. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Zhen: I used to give it on exams, so it cannot be really hard :-) I mentioned this, because it shows that it is impossible to give a coherent semantics for lambda calculi with double-negation rule in cartesian closed categories; that is: it is easy to find a non-degenerated CCC with $\neg\neg A \rightarrow A$ and $\neg\neg A \leftarrow A$ for every object $A$, so one may wonder if it is possible to find a coherent collection of morphisms $\neg\neg A \rightarrow A$, which are not necessary the inversion of the canonical $\neg\neg A \leftarrow A$ --- it turns out, it is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Let's prove something stronger: every infinitary-distributive complete lattice is a complete Heyting algebra (and so cartesian closed as a category).

Recall, a complete lattice is a partial order in which *all* meets and joins exist. The powerset of a set is certainly a complete lattice, and it moreover satisfies the infinite distributive law:
$$\left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \cap B = \bigcup_{i \in I} (A_i \cap B)$$
Now the claim is that such a complete lattice has a Heyting operation, i.e. a binary operation $\to$ such that $A \subseteq (B \to C)$ if and only if $A \cap B \subseteq C$ for all $A$. How do we do this? Let's apply wishful thinking. Suppose we had such a $(B \to C)$; then $(B \to C) \subseteq (B \to C)$, and in particular, $(B \to C)$ must be the greatest $A$ such that $A \cap B \subseteq C$. On the other hand, we are in a complete lattice, so we can certainly define
$$(B \to C) = \bigcup \{ A : A \cap B \subseteq C \}$$
and this works: if $A \subseteq (B \to C)$, then 
$$A \cap B \subseteq (B \to C) \cap B = \left( \bigcup \{ A : A \cap B \subseteq C \} \right) \cap B = \bigcup \{ A \cap B : A \cap B \subseteq C \} \subseteq C$$
by the infinite distributive law; the converse is automatic by construction of $(B \to C)$.

The nice thing about this proof is that it is completely constructive and can be internalised in any topos. But in the classical setting, we can be a little bit more explicit about what $(B \to C)$ is: writing $B^{\mathsf{c}}$ for the complement of $B$, we have $(B \to C) = B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup C$. Clearly, $(B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup C) \cap B = C \cap B \subseteq C$, so $(B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup C) \subseteq (B \to C)$; on the other hand, if $A \cap B \subseteq C$, then $B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup C$, and clearly
$$A = A \cap (B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup B) = (A \cap B^{\mathsf{c}}) \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup (A \cap B)$$
so $A \subseteq B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup C$, and therefore $(B \to C) \subseteq B^{\mathsf{c}} \cup C$, as required. (Exercise: Where have I used the law of excluded middle in this argument?)

Comment: I think in a general topos, you could also write $(B \rightarrow C)_{\mathcal{P}(S)} = \{ x \in S \mid x \in B \rightarrow x \in C \}$.  Then, in the classical setting, $x \in B \rightarrow x \in C$ is equivalent to $x \notin B \lor x \in C \iff x \in B^c \cup C$.

Answer (score -1):

I found this question in Pierce's book and have been working on it today. Here's what I've got:

**The Problem:** The exponent $B^A$ needs to be a member of the powerset. Moreover it has to satisfy the following constraints:

- There is a map from $B^A \times A$ to $B$.

  - in terms of sets, $B^A \times A \subseteq B$
- For every other powerset object $C$ such that $g: C \times A \rightarrow B$ exists, we need a unique map from $C$ to $B$

  - again in terms of sets, we must show that for all $C$ such that $C \times A \subseteq B$, the relation $C \subseteq B$ must hold.

**Solution:** If $B \subset A$ then $B^A = B$. Otherwise $B^A = S$ (the final object in our powerset category).

**Justification:** If $B \subset A$ then $B^A$ must be a subset of $B$ for $B^A \times A \subseteq B$ to hold. We deduce that $B^A$ must be $B$ exactly because it is the only choice that guarantees $C \subseteq B^A$ for every $C$ such that $C^A \times A \subseteq B$.

If $A \subseteq B$ then $B^A \times A \subseteq B$ holds for any choice of $B^A$. Likewise, we can use any powerset element $C$ to satisfy $C^A \times A \subseteq B$. Because of this, $B^A$ has to be the entire set $S$. It is the only choice that guarantees $C \subseteq B^A$ for every valid choice of $C$.

Answer (score -1):

By definition, the right adjoint $B^{A}$ must be satisfy the equivalence
$$C\subset B^{A}\Leftrightarrow C\cap A\subset B$$
for all $C\in \mathcal{P}(S)$. In particular, this must hold for all singletons $\{s\}$. Thus we must have
$$s\in B^{A}\Leftrightarrow \{s\}\subset B^{A}\Leftrightarrow \{s\}\cap A\subset B.$$
This last inclusion holds if and only if $s\in S\setminus A$ or $s\in B$, thus the exponential object must be given by $$B^{A}=B\cup (S\setminus A).$$